# Ubuntu/Nginx SSL certificate not working

Tags: ssl, nginx

I am having trouble installing a SSL cert on an ubuntu server with NGINX/Nodejs.

on the /etc/nginx/sites-enable/website file I have

```
server {

  listen *:443 default_server ssl;
  listen 80;

  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/myserver.key;
  ssl_certificate /etc/sscl/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt;

  server_name  XXX.example.io;

  root /var/www/example/public/;

  client_max_body_size 100M;
  open_file_cache max=200000 inactive=20s;
  open_file_cache_valid 30s;
  open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
  open_file_cache_errors on;


  error_log /var/log/nginx/example_error.log warn;

  try_files $uri @example2;

  log_not_found on;

  log_subrequest on;

  location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
    expires 1d;
  }

  location @example2 {
    proxy_pass http://record;
  }


}
```

When I netstat to see if the port 443 is being listened to its not (netstat -antlp)

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      1022/sshd       
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3000            0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      19976/nodejs    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      30164/nodejs    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*              LISTEN      5656/nginx           
.......................

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                   LISTEN      1022/sshd
```

Any ideas as to why NGINX isn't even listening for the port 443? I have opened it on AWS.

Comment: Anything in the error logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve the issue, a missing ; as usual, thanks for the reply

Comment: go ahead and mark this a the correct answer so that this can be close off

Answer (score 0):

I would also suggest not listening to both ports 80 and 443 in the same config. I suggest setting up server redirects, e.g.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   server_name endyourif.com www.endyourif.com;
   return 301 https://www.endyourif.com$request_uri;
}
```

[Setting up SSL with nginx including redirects from non HTTPS traffic](https://www.endyourif.com/setting-up-ssl-with-nginx-including-redirects-from-non-https-traffic/)